# Jenkins cli command return authentication error

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, jenkins-cli

I tried to test my Jenkins on Ubuntu, by running the command from the Jenkins CLI section:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ help
```

And got the error:

**Error: You must authenticate to access this Jenkins**

How do I write command with authentications?

Answer (score 1):

In order to run command with authentication, you need to specify the --username and the --password parameters, as shown in this image:

[image]